# A sequence of continuous periodic functions converges to 0 weakly in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given a continuous function $h$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
h(x+T) = h(x)
$$
for some $T>0$ and all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Also, $\int_{[0,T]} = 0$. How do we prove that $f_n(x) := h(nx)$ converges to $0$ weakly in $L^p([a,b])$ for $1\leq p < \infty$? How does the fact $\int_{[0,T]} = 0$ will help? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $\int_0^T h(t) dt = 0$ helps, because in general you will converge weakly to the mean.

Consider $g = \mathbb{1}_{(c, d)}$ for some interval $c < d$. Then :

$$ \int_a^b f_n(x) g(x) dx = \frac{1}{n} \int_{nc}^{nd} h(x) dx $$

Now, you can separate $(nc, nd)$ as $(nc, mT)$, $(mT, MT)$, $(MT, nd)$ with $m, M$ depending on $n, c, d$ such that $nc \leq mT \leq MT \leq nd$ and $|nd - MT| \leq T$, $|mT - nc| \leq T$, so that :

$$ \left| \int_a^b f_n(x) g(x) dx \right| \leq \frac{1}{n} \Vert h \Vert_{\infty} (nd - MT + mT - nc) \leq \frac{2T}{n} \Vert h \Vert_{\infty} \to 0 $$

where I simplified the middle part by periodicity of $h$ and $\int_0^T h(x) dx = 0$.

Now if $g$ is a finite linear combination of $\mathbb{1}_{(c, d)}$, by linearity you also have $\int f_n g \to 0$. You conclude by density of such functions in $L^p$.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering the question. Would you mind explaining how to simplify the middle part by introducing the norm in $L^\infty$? Also, what do you mean by density of such functions?

Comment: Actually, the middle part is $0$ ; the norm on $h$ come from the sides $(nc, mT)$ and $(MT, nd)$. I forgot to say that $m$, $M$ are integers ! The density is a common fact in Lebesgue theory : these are "simple functions" and they are actually a way to define Lebesgue integration (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_function )

Comment: Thanks. I understand what a simple function is. But I wonder if we used the property of denseness here? If so, what functions are dense and why? Also, I am curious where the first equality comes from, i.e., $\int \cdots = \frac{1}{n} \int \cdots$.

Comment: The first inequality is a change of variable. The property of density is simply saying that you can approach every $L^{p'}$ function with a simple function and therefore you get weak convergence in $L^p$ for $1 \leq p < \infty$ ($p = \infty$ fails because its dual is not $L^1$).